# upload page layout in sharepoint 2013 without wsp solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I designed my own page layout (with html, css, js and sp controls)
and I wanna upload him to my site (sp 2013 publishing site).

The thing is that I have no solution(wsp) to deploy my site,
so I want to upload my layout directly to the site catalog (as I uploaded a masterpage).

There is a way to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are uisng the Sharepoint 2013 
then try following steps and you may be able to upload them easily:

1. map your local drive as a map drive to the server.
2. By this uploading these page layouts becomes very easy. Simply drag and drop the files into your Master Page Gallery.
3. In SharePoint, refresh the Master Page Gallery page to see that the two page layouts have been added. Also notice that an associated ASP.NET file has been created for each of the page layouts.

Reference :http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/04/10/stage-7-upload-page-layouts-and-create-new-pages-in-a-publishing-site.aspx

Thanks

Comment: thanks but actually my layout file is already aspx file, anyway I already did it, and still my layouts havent shown when I created a new page.

Comment: Did you published that layout ?

Comment: Did you set up properties for page layout? You need to set `Content Type` and `Assosiated Content Type`.

Comment: where do I need to set them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.
I solved the problem with SP designer, 
I created a new layout via sp designer,
but I also saw that I could do it with design manager.